# How to handle data encryption in sql procedure and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, encryption

We want to store encrypted data in our database. Our application uses ibernate and also we have some stored procedures which uses data directly from database. the data is being displayed on UI so the data should be decrypted before sending to the UI. The procedure do a comparison on the data so either this needs to be done on dycrypted data or the encrypted data should not be encrypted using salt.

Apart from the database we also store the data on AWS elastic search which is used to search plain text.

What would the best way so the our encryption dycription logic can be managed from single source for the data stored on various places.

Comment: Use your own encryption algorithm e.g 3DES with a key and IV. Whenn storing the data encrypt it and decrypt it using the same algorithm while displaying.

Comment: If we use our own algorithm, we would need to implement it in both, java code as well as stored procedure which I don't want.

Comment: do you want to query on the encrypted value?

Comment: No, we need to run plain text search queries.